# Implementing fread, fopen, and fwrite in C concurrently using two functions result in error?

Tags: c

Good Morning,

I have just finished my source code that contains a function to take the elements of an array and write it to a file and another function after that that copies the elements in the newly created file to a new array. Note that I will be frank here, this is homework for me, and I am finished. However, the weird thing is that when I perform my own tests, it works, but when I submit it to an online correctness checker, it seems to fail with large numbers.

My code is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;


int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
     FILE *fp;
     int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*ia->len+1);
     tmp[0] = ia->len;

     int i=0;
     for(i = 0; i<ia->len+1; i++)
     {
          tmp[i+1] = ia->data[i];

     }  
     fp = fopen( filename , "wb" );
     fwrite(tmp, sizeof(int), ia->len+1, fp );
     fclose( fp );
     return 0;
}

 intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
 {
     int i = 0;
     intarr_t *tmp = malloc( sizeof( intarr_t ) );
     if(tmp==NULL)
     {
         return NULL;
     }
     FILE *fp;  
     fp = fopen( filename , "r" );
     int len;
     fread( &len, sizeof(int), 1, fp );
     tmp->len = len;
     tmp->data = malloc( ( len ) * sizeof( int ) );
     if(tmp->data == NULL)
     {
         return NULL;
     }
     fread(tmp->data, sizeof(int), len, fp);
     fclose(fp);
     return tmp;
}
```

So, the first function takes a char array containing the file name and an structure which I have defined at the very top and the gist of it is that I make a new array of length +1 and store the length of the original array passed to me by the struct in first index and the remaining indice will store the elements. Then I store all the stuff in it into a file. After that I call my SECOND function and open the very same file and read the first thing in the file which is the length and then I use that length to read the remaining things in the file to a new array. After that I return a pointer to it.

The hint the online code check gives me is that it aborted possibly due to a failed assert or length of original array does not match length of new array.

**The only major problem I personally see is that in my typedef I have unsigned int len and in my functions I use int len. Or that I am not freeing the first tmp array I make using malloc in first function. but I don't think that should affect the result..

Comment: at intarr_save_binary : `int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*ia->len+1);` --> `int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*(ia->len+1));`, `for(i = 0; i<ia->len+1; i++)` --> `for(i = 0; i<ia->len; i++)`  note : `int???_t;` system reserved name.

Comment: Would it also be favourable to free the tmp array in my first function or is that alright since the computer will eventually fix it.

Comment: this would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com, but FWIW I would make your structure mirror the file format (i.e. put the length first) and then avoid the temporary array - just perform one `fwrite()` for the length field and another for the actual data.  Avoiding the temporary array would incidentally make moot the error in your `malloc` calculation where the `+ 1` is applied to late.

Comment: I think I tried your method before, but one of the tutors said that it could overwrite the first fwrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without better diagnostics from the online code check that you are using, it is really hard to pinpoint the error. If you suspect that the online code check fails for larger numbers (array sizes?) you may want to extend your own tests to better cover that scenario. If you suspect that the error is a segmentation fault (which I think could be the case, see below) you can also try to run your program in a tool like valgrind, which can tell you if you have any illegal memory access. A bug like that could work by accident on your local system but fail on a different system.

That being said, I think you have a bug in `intarr_save_binary` when you access the memory that you allocate with `malloc`. Look closely at how many bytes of memory you allocate. Say that `ia->len` is 3 and `sizeof(int)` is 4, in this case you are allocating `3*4 + 1 = 13` bytes, clearly not enough to hold 4 ints. In addition you seem to have an [Off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in the following loop.